# Access Analyzer Service Linked Role is not in the organizational management account

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, aws-iam-access-analyzer

im trying to enable IAM access analyzer at the org level via a default admin in a security account (All in terraform).

In the root of the org account i have:

- updated the aws_service_access_principals to include "access-analyzer.amazonaws.com"

```
resource "aws_organizations_organization" "org" {
  feature_set = "ALL"
  aws_service_access_principals = [
    ...
    "access-analyzer.amazonaws.com"
  ]

  enabled_policy_types = [
    "SERVICE_CONTROL_POLICY"
  ]
}
```

- Created a `aws_organizations_delegated_administrator`_for the security account and the `accessanalyzer`

```
resource "aws_organizations_delegated_administrator" "example" {
  account_id        = var.security_account
  service_principal = "access-analyzer.amazonaws.com"
}
```

In the security account i enabled `access-analyzer` with `type` set to `organization`

```
resource "aws_accessanalyzer_analyzer" "accessanalyzer" {
  analyzer_name = "test"
  type          = "ORGANIZATION"
}
```

When this runs i get the error:

```
Error: error creating Access Analyzer Analyzer (openc): ConflictException: Access Analyzer Service Linked Role is not in the organizational management account
│ {
│   RespMetadata: {
│     StatusCode: 409,
│     RequestID: "1c597ce0-4c59-4115-89aa-437cdc8156d5"
│   },
│   Message_: "Access Analyzer Service Linked Role is not in the organizational management account"
│ }
│ 
│   with aws_accessanalyzer_analyzer.accessanalyzer,
│   on access-analyzer.tf line 1, in resource "aws_accessanalyzer_analyzer" "accessanalyzer":
│    1: resource "aws_accessanalyzer_analyzer" "accessanalyzer" {
│ 
╵
```

Any idea why this is erroring? i was expecting the delegate admin to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing and need to Create "AWSServiceRoleForAccessAnalyzer" role on the Master "Organization" Account, easiest way by creating an Analyzer on the Master account and then the role will be created automatically

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access-analyzer-getting-started.html

then try to apply your Terraform code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).